# What is the reason for "ERROR TypeError: this.onChange is not a function"?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

My code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btdpo1).

Would you tell me the browser return the following error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.onChange is not a function
at RichTextEditorComponent.forwardEvent (rich-text-editor.component.ts:39)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (RichTextEditorComponent.html:6)
```

I have tried to print the "this" object to console, it returns the "RichTextEditorComponent" object only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a problem inside your `RichTextEditorComponent` where you declare `onChange` and `onTouched` to be of type `function` without really assigning them the actual function.

```
onChange: (value:any) => {};
onTouched: () => {};
```

It should be rewritten as follows (using `=`)

```
onChange = (value:any) => {};
onTouched = () => {};
```

Answer (score 1):

While the type of onChange is a function, I don't see anything actually setting the value, it is undefined (hence, not a function).

In `rich-text-editor.component.ts`:

```js
onChange: (value:any) => {};

// and

registerOnChange(fn: any) {
  this.onChange = fn;
}
```

Nothing is calling `registerOnChange` to set the value of `onChange`.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the form is initialized in OnInit. It should be initialized in AfterViewInit.